# Fab in Coordinator layout with bottom padding

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Fab is in coordinator layout, coordinator layout has bottom padding.
There is incorrect fab behavior when snackbar showing:

Snackbar appeared:

[image]

Snackbar disappeared

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_categories_white_24dp"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.FabAwareScrollingViewBehavior"
        tools:listItem="@layout/list_item_view"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actions_list_empty_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.Subhead"
        android:text="@string/list_empty_result"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorHint"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_white_24dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What can I do to avoid this incorrect fab behavior when snackbar disappeared? Fab must place in bottom right corner, but it is located slightly below the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your fab

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

snackbar

rootLayout, on your case use your coordinator layout id

```
Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Hello Snackbar!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Thanks! But after run this I got the exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: This graph contains cyclic dependencies

Comment: post your BottomNavigationView, or double check your usage of layout_anchor

Comment: I think bottomnavigationview does not affect on fab, because bottomnavigationview placed in main activity, and my screen is an activity view child. Seems that coordinator layout with behaviors act to fab when snackbar showing, and coordinator layout bottom padding has great importance

Comment: You guys missed `"+"` in `app:layout_anchor="@id/list"`. Try with this: `app:layout_anchor="@+id/list"` if it didn't solve the issue, remove the line and this one: `android:paddingBottom="56dp"`

Comment: `"+"` is unnecessary here. And `layout_anchor` does not work, if there is `layout_behavior`. I can not remove bottom padding

Comment: @AlexeyNikitin, layout_anchor still works even with layout_behavior. Replace your layout_behavior with this app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" –. And also are you using coordinator layout on your parent and child activity?

Comment: @RenzManacmol yes, I replaced `layout_bahvior` and added `layout_anchor` and I did not get a crash, but strange fab behavior still works

Comment: @RenzManacmol no, parent activity using `framelayout`, coordinator layout placed only in child view

Comment: Use your coordinator layout as root/view for your snackbar

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed your comment... Yes, I use coordinator as root for snackbar, for now I did not find the solution :(

Comment: What is the version of your support library?

Comment: @RenzManacmol `27.1.1`